# Can the Windows 10 firewall be configured to block a specific application from accessing the internet, but allow it to access the local intranet?

Tags: windows-10, windows-firewall

The background to my question is that there is a pane "Scope" for each outbound rule of the Windows 10 defender firewall in which settings for the local IP address and remote IP address can be made independently of each other.

However, the setting that every remote IP address and only one special local IP address (e.g. 192.168.1.254, which is not used) is set does not work with a blocking rule -> nothing is blocked, neither addresses from the Internet still address from the local network ...

Can somebody tell me why? Is there a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default a program can do unrestricted outgoing connections,
so you need to add a rule to block it from accessing the internet.
It does not need a specific rule to allow it to access the local internet,
since this is allowed by default.

Assuming that your local network IP range is `192.168.1.x`,
you will need two rules for the application. The Rule Type needs to be Custom:

1. Block the range from `0.0.0.0` to `192.168.0.255`
2. Block the range from `192.168.2.0` to `255.255.255.255`

[image]

Comment: harrymc, you are my hero! it works like clockwork ... what an elegant solution! I would never have thought of that ... many, many, many thanks!